# Why arrow function is different when adding prototype

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype, arrow-functions

I just wondered why this code run correctly with normal function and resulted in a different result when using arrow function:

the code:

```
String.prototype.addDotAfter = function() {
  return `${this}.`;
}
let ahmed = 'ahmed';

console.log(ahmed.addDotAfter()) // = ahmed.
```

the other code that return strange result:

```
String.prototype.addDotAfter = ()=> {
  return `${this}.`;
}
let ahmed = 'ahmed';

console.log(ahmed.addDotAfter()) // = [object Object].
```

I don't know why they are different in result!

Comment: Because arrow functions binds `this`. It is by design. Arrow functions were deliberately designed to be **different** from regular functions and the **only** difference is how it deals with `this`.

Comment: @slebetman No, _“arrow functions binds `this`”_ is misleading. The value of `this` immediately inside an arrow function is _the same value_ immediately outside the arrow function; or more concisely: in arrow function bodies, `this` comes from the _lexical scope_ of the arrow function itself. Binding refers to actually receiving an own `this` value. That’s what [`bind`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does; arrow functions ignore binding.

Comment: @SebastianSimon No. The definition of binding in computer science is calculating which object a method operates on. Even in languages that don't normally use the `this` keyword like Java and C++ we call it binding. I'm talking about binding, not the `.bind` method

Comment: @slebetman The word “binding” has other semantics in JavaScript, including those that mean the opposite of what arrow functions do. That’s why it’s misleading to refer to this as “binding”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon No. While the word `binding` may have some additional meaning you understand it **also** has the completely ordinary meaning that I'm using: that is the computation of the value of `this`. Your understanding is completely wrong and is contrary to the use of the word `binding` in the ECMAScript spec (currently ECMAScript 2015 6th Edition). When talking about getting the value of the keyword `this` from the lexical environment (what you are saying) the spec says: `supplies the binding of the keyword this`. The ES6 spec uses the word binding the same way I do

Comment: .. someone else may have been misleading you to think that `binding` means something different. In which case I stand by my comment in order to educate misinformed people like you.

Comment: @SebastianSimon For reference see the spec's use of the word `binding`: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-resolvethisbinding

Comment: @slebetman (1/3) _“currently ECMAScript 2015 6th Edition”_ — That’s not the current spec at all; ECMAScript 2022 is the current spec. You can also refer to the [living spec](//tc39.es/ecma262); the abstract operations there are the same as for ECMAScript 2015, though. The abstract operation you linked to (ResolveThisBinding) calls GetThisEnvironment, which calls HasThisBinding on a given environment record first. If HasThisBinding returns **false**, then it checks the outer environment reference, until it reaches the global environment record.

Comment: @slebetman (2/3) The [HasThisBinding](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records-hasthisbinding) abstract operation tells you if an environment has a `this` binding or not. Environments with the “lexical” [[ThisBindingStatus]] internal slot _do not_ have a `this` binding (“return **false**”). [BindThisValue](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bindthisvalue) binds the `this` value, first asserting that this internal slot it _not_ “lexical”.

Comment: @slebetman (3/3) [NewFunctionEnvironment](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newfunctionenvironment) sets the [[ThisBindingStatus]] corresponsing to [[ThisMode]], which, in turn, is set from [OrdinaryFunctionCreate](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryfunctioncreate). Arrow functions are exactly those functions where [[ThisMode]] is set to “lexical”. But this means that HasThisBinding would return **false** for environment records corresponding to arrow functions. This is exactly why I can claim that arrow functions do _not_ bind `this`.